Explanation of a part of a proof for continuous and bijective mapping in a compact space implies continous inverse mapping
I am having troubles with understanding the proof below:
Let $X$ be a compact space, and let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous and bijective mapping. Then the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is continuous.
Let $y_0 \in Y$ and $(y_n)$ be a sequence of points in $Y$ converging to $y_0$. Let $g = f^{-1}$ and $x_n = g(y_n)$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots$. We will verify that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x_0$.
Assume that $x_0$ is not the limit of the sequence $(x_n)$. Then there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $(x_{p_n})$ such that $\rho(x_{p_n}, x_0) \geq \varepsilon$. Since the space $X$ is compact, we can extract a subsequence $(x_{r_n})$ from $(x_{p_n})$ that converges to some point $\bar{x} \in X$, where $\bar{x} \neq x_0$.
By the continuity of the function $f$, we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_{r_n}) = f(\bar{x}).
$$
Since $y_{r_n} = f(x_{r_n})$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = y_0$, it follows that $y_0 = f(\bar{x})$. By the injectivity of the function $f$, we obtain $y_0 = f(x_0) \neq f(\bar{x})$, which leads to a contradiction. Therefore, the function $f^{-1}$ is continuous.
Two things I do not understand:
a) Why can we always find some subsequence $(x_{p_n})$ such that $\rho(x_{p_n}, x_0) \geq \varepsilon$
b) Since a space is compact, we can pick a subsequence of any sequence and this subsequence will converge, what guarantees us that a subsequence $(x_{r_n})$ from $(x_{p_n})$ will converge to some point that is different than $x_0$?

Hint for a): take the negation in the definition of the limit in a metric space. For b): what do you get when taking the limit in $\rho(x_{r_n}, x_0) \geq \varepsilon$?

For a), there exists then $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $n \geq n_0$ such that: $\rho(x_{n}, x_{0}) \geq 0$
For b), do you mean taking the limit of $\lim_{n \to + \infty} \rho(x_{r_{n}}, x_0)$?

By negating the definition of convergence, it can be shown that the statement "$x_n$ does not converge to $x_0$" is equivalent to the following:
$$\exists \varepsilon > 0 \ \text{ such that } \ \forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \ \exists n \ge N \text{ with } \rho(x_n, x_0) \ge \varepsilon$$
We construct a subsequence inductively as follows:

Let $p_1$ be such that $\rho(x_{p_1}, x_0) \ge \varepsilon$.
Let $N = p_1 + 1$, and let $p_2$ be the smallest natural number greater than or equal to $N$ such that $\rho(x_{p_2}, x_0) \ge \varepsilon$.
Let $N = p_2 + 1$, and let $p_3 \dots$

By construction, $\rho(x_{p_n}, x_0) \ge \varepsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
For your second question, this just follows from the fact that $x_{r_n}$ is a subsequence of $x_{p_n}$ (technically, it would be better to call this sequence $x_{r_{p_n}}$ to follow the subsequence notation convention, but things can get messy quickly with nested indices). Recall that we constructed $x_{p_n}$ so that $\rho(x_{p_n}, x_0) \ge \varepsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In particular, this must hold whenever $p_n = r_n$, and so $x_{r_n}$ certainly cannoty converge to $x_0$.

For b), is it fair to say then that if a sequence diverges, does that imply that every subsequence also diverges with the same point as the original sequence?
For a) What guarantees that point 1. is valid? How can we know that it works for our $p_1$? Is it because we choose some point from the points of the original sequence?

No, a sequence can fail to converge and still have convergent subsequences, but that is not relevant to the argument either way. The subsequence $x_{r_n}$ does converge, but it can't converge to $x_0$ because $\rho(x_{r_n}, x_0) \ge \varepsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $\varepsilon > 0$ is fixed. You can also argue as Bruno B suggested. The metric is continuous, $x_{r_n}$ converges (say to $\bar{x}$), and limits respect inequalities. This will show you that $\rho(\bar{x}, x_0) \ge \varepsilon$. By non-degeneracy, $\bar{x} \ne x_0$.

For $a)$, I simply used the definition of "$x_n$ does not converge to $x_0$" that I supplied. Choose $N = 1$ in the definition, for example. Then, there necessarily exists some $n \ge 1$ with $\rho(x_n, x_0) \ge \varepsilon$. You can take this $n$ to be $p_1$.

I understand a) point 1 now.
For b):
"You can also argue as Bruno B suggested" -> so taking the limit would imply that $\rho(\overline{x}, x_0) \geq \epsilon$, since limits respect inequalities, it would be impossible for $\overline{x}$ to be $x_0$ because that would imply $0 \geq \epsilon > 0$, is that correct?
For a) also: is this an example of a proof-by-construction? Or did you just use induction to prove that $\rho(x_{p_{n+1}}) \geq \epsilon$? (notice n+1 index)

Well, yes. $\bar{x} = x_0$ if and only if $\rho(\bar{x}, x_0) = 0$, and $\epsilon > 0$. And I wouldn't exactly call what I wrote in the original answer a proof by construction, as I haven't constructed a definite subsequence. I just showed that there exists some such subsequence. You could make it constructive by fixing $\varepsilon > 0$ (say, one half of the supremum of all such $\varepsilon>0$), and then choosing $p_1$ to be the smallest natural number with $\rho(x_{p_1}, x_0) \ge \varepsilon$, though I don't see any reason to do so.
